# Have one object call the functions for two objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, master-slave

```cpp
class foo{
 public:

  void print();
  void alert();
  bool get_state();
};

class bar: public foo{};

bar master;
bar slave;
```

Is there a way to have calls to `slave` call the same function for `slave` and `master`?

There are unfortunately 2 catches.

1. This should not be implemented for all functions.

```cpp
master.get_state() //Returns master.get_state()
slave.get_state()  //Returns master.get_state() || slave.get_state()

master.alert() //Calls master.alert()
slave.alert()  //Calls master.alert() and slave.alert()

master.print() //Calls master.print()
slave.print()  //Calls slave.print()
```

2. I also don't have access to the implementation of `foo` and I would definitely prefer not having to override all of `foo`'s functions in `bar`.

Comment: Please use the `class` keyword instead of `Class`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I did that. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have calls to `slave` call the same function for `slave` and `master`?

No, an object is an object, not two objects. In no language is it possible to combine two different objects into one, because they hold different states and combining them breaks the basic concept of "object". If you find it a necessity, it implies either you are not clear about what you want, or there may be design flaws in `foo`.

---

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve, here are some hints.

If you are trying to call the non-virtual methods of the base class, use `this->BASE::METHOD` to break the shadow:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class foo {
public:
    void print() { // Impls just for demonstration
        std::cout << "printed by foo" << std::endl;
    };
    void alert() {
        std::cout << "alert from foo" << std::endl;
    };
    bool get_state() {
        return false;
    };
};

class bar : public foo {
public:
    void print() {
        this->foo::print();
        std::cout << "printed by bar" << std::endl;
    }
    void alert() {
        this->foo::alert();
        std::cout << "alert from bar" << std::endl;
    }
    bool get_state() {
        bool my_state = true;
        return my_state || this->foo::get_state();
    }
};

int main() {
    foo master;
    bar slave;

    std::cout << "MASTER: " << std::boolalpha << master.get_state() << std::endl;
    master.print();
    master.alert();

    std::cout << "\nSLAVE: " << std::boolalpha << slave.get_state() << std::endl;
    slave.print();
    slave.alert();
}
```

Output:

```
MASTER: false
printed by foo
alert from foo

SLAVE: true
printed by foo
printed by bar
alert from foo
alert from bar
```

---

Or, if you want two `foo`s, but you don't want two objects on the caller's side, favor composition over inheritance.

```cpp
class composition {
private:
    foo _master;
    foo _slave;

public:
    void combinedPrint() {
        _master.print();
        _slave.print();
    }
    // same for alert() and get_state()
};
```

---

Or, if you want the above composition, but you *REALLY* need `composition` to behave like a `foo` (i.e. you're hiding the caller from the fact that `composition` is actually a holder of two `foo`s), extract an interface:

```cpp
class IFoo {
public:
    virtual ~IFoo() = default;

    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual void alert() = 0;
    virtual bool get_state() = 0;
};
```

And modify `foo` to implement `IFoo` (yes you'd have to, but in a simple, non-destructive way):

```cpp
class foo : IFoo { /* Body unmodified... */ }
```

Also `composition`:

```cpp
class composition : IFoo {
private:
    foo _master;
    foo _slave;

public:
    void print() {
        _master.print();
        _slave.print();
    };
    // same for alert() and get_state()
};
```